# Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make it create a role in `discord.js` and give it to a user, but I seem to get this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.

Here's my code:

```js
let d = msg.guild.roles.create({
 data: {
  name: '{:robot: Bot Developer}',
  color: 'ff00aa',
  permissions: 'ADMINISTRATOR',
 },
});
msg.member.roles.add(d);
```

Comment: Try to do `msg.member.roles.add(d.id)`

Comment: The problem is that you are adding the role before it is fully created. Use `async msg.guild.roles.create(...)` or use a `.then()` statement

Comment: None of those work @OctagonalT

Answer (score 2):

According to the Discord.js Documentation, [RoleManager.create()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create) returns a Promise with the role.

Since you do not have an `await` or a `.then`, `d` is probably `Promise { <pending> }`.
Assuming you are running in an async function, the following code should work.

```
let d = await msg.guild.roles.create({
 data: {
  name: '{:robot: Bot Developer}',
  color: 'ff00aa',
  permissions: 'ADMINISTRATOR',
 },
});
msg.member.roles.add(d);
```

If you are in a situation where you cannot use an async function, the following is an alternative

```
msg.guild.roles.create({
 data: {
  name: '{:robot: Bot Developer}',
  color: 'ff00aa',
  permissions: 'ADMINISTRATOR',
 },
}).then(d => {
 msg.member.roles.add(d);
 // Continue on with what you want to do.
})
```

If you run into an error that includes `await is only valid in an async function`, make sure your function is async by changing this:

```
function foo() {
OR (depending on your code)
client.on('message', message =>
```

to

```
async function foo() {
OR (depending on your code)
client.on('message', async message =>
```